# Does Java Spring 3.0 MVC support annotation/attribute based client side validation like Asp.net MVC 2.0?

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, annotations

In Asp.Net MVC 2.0, at least in the beta, you could decoration your model classes with data annotation attributes and enable client side validation that leverages that criteria defined in your model data annotation attibutes. Is there anything similar for Java Spring MVC 3.0?

Is it possible to inject a component into the response pipeline that can inspect the model's annotated properties and render client side validation logic to complement the server side validation logic that is invoked prior to the controller handling the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring MVC is a fairly low level framework. It doesn't extend to doing client side validation.

There are other Java Web frameworks that do this such as Tapestry, Wicket and JSF (IceFaces, etc). These are what I tend to call "component frameworks".

Answer (score 4):

Actually, [there is something](http://wheelersoftware.com/articles/spring-bean-validation-framework.html) a little bit like it, based on the JSR-303 Bean Validation spec, which is now final and [fully supported by Spring 3.0](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation).

Recently, as part of Spring Webflow, Springsource has released Spring JS (javascript) which uses Dojo. You can use that for your client side validation. [Check out this howto](http://stsmedia.net/spring-finance-part-4-spring-js-dojo-bean-validation/)

Obviously, component-frameworks such as Wicket (like fraido mentioned) have better support for this kind of usecase. So if you have to implement a lot of similar usecases, that is probably a better fit for your project. However, if it is sporadic, Spring JS / Bean validation could be the way to go.

Comment: I used Spring JS and I've to say that it's very limited.

Comment: Yes it is, that's why I said in my answer that it is only a good choice if there is not *that* many usecases in his project that require extensive validation.

Answer (score 2):

In Spring MVC 3.0 there's nothing like that at the moment. 
As cletus said frameworks like Tapestry ([ex](http://blog.tapestry5.de/index.php/2010/01/04/tapestry-and-jsr-303-bean-validation-api/)), Wicket ([ex](http://blog.zenika.com/index.php?post/2010/02/24/Wicket-JSR-303-Validators)) and others have some sort of Client Validation that uses JavaScript to validate forms etc.
You can write your own validation Jstl taglib maybe with the help of a JS Library ([jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), ...) and Plugins like : [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

**edit**: I've just found this: [Mediawidget](http://metawidget.org/). Maybe it's worth having a look.
It says: "Metawidget reads Bean Validation annotations and generates forms with 
widgets that are pre-configured for minimum/maximum values, lengths etc."

Spring integration [Link1](http://metawidget.sourceforge.net/doc/reference/en/htmlsingle/metawidget.html#section-introduction-part2-web), [Link2](http://metawidget.sourceforge.net/doc/reference/en/htmlsingle/metawidget.html#section-introduction-part2-web)

Answer (score 1):

This project looks to be exactly what you're looking for: http://kenai.com/projects/jsr303js

2011-12-06: I'm just about to try it myself

2013-12-09: Update on this answer: I did try the library out, and it worked very well. It needed some tweaking (it's a prototype patch for Spring, not a finished plugin), but it was the best solution I could find at the time. Perhaps there is a new solution, or perhaps someone has finished off this prototype since I posted? If not, I can recommend this one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a variation on what's already been said, but one of the big strengths of Spring-MVC is its ability to integrate with other libraries, like the different JSF variations that do give client side validation.